# Sending HTTP request through cron job

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have a PHP file that is deployed in a server:

```
/var/www/html/cron/leave_mail.php
```

The code inside this PHP file is just sending a request via CURL (The server of the url is the same server of the cron job):

```
<?php

$url = "http://my-site.build.com/sendmail/sendmail_leave";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$head = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Now I created a cron job on the same server where I deployed the PHP file:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/cron/leave_mail.php
```

After 1 minute, it didn't execute the command inside the PHP file, however, I can see on the system logs that the cron job runs.

I run my local virtual machine with ubuntu os and created the same cron job, executing the same file. After 1 min, I can see that it executes the command inside the PHP file because the data on the database was updated.

I'm really puzzled on why the cron job on the server didn't executes the PHP command. I'm stuck on this issue.

Comment: On some systems, you need to specify the path of PHP as well: `/usr/bin/php` or wherever it might be

Comment: You need to distinguish between it failing to execute the PHP script at all, and the PHP crashing in some way, and the cURL request not doing what you expected. Ensuring the PHP has error logging switched on, and also that you record the response from the cURL request, would help with that. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged (and others) for info on working out what has gone wrong with a cron job.

Comment: Add this to the end of the crontab entry. `> ~/test.log 2>&1` it will send all output to a logfile in the users home directory.

Comment: I have another cron job that executes another PHP file. The PHP file is just accessing the database through mysqli and update the records. And this PHP file is in the same directory with leave_mail.php. And the cron job running this file has no problem at all. My problem is with the cron job running the leave_mail.php because it didn't execute the command if the job is in the server, however, if I run it via cron job on my local virtual machine, it just works fine. So I'm really puzzled what happened.

Comment: Can you run the file manually on the server?

Comment: @aynber Yeah, I run it manually on the server's terminal, and it took around 1min to complete its run. But when I check the database, nothing happens. I tried running it manually also on my local virtual machine, it only takes less than 10secs to run, and it updates the data on the database.

Comment: You'll need to do some troubleshooting, then. You can also bypass the cURL request and just run the actual file that the cURL request is trying to access.

Comment: I actually done a lot of troubleshooting until I lost hope. I can't run the file that the cURL is trying to access because it's using a framework (it can only be accessed by sending request). That's why I use another PHP file to send request.

Answer (score 0):

Start with finding where PHP is:

```
which php
```

Then update the crontab by running the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

Then update the line with the correct PHP path:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron/leave_mail.php
```

Also note that you can specify the user before the path.
Hopes this helps a little.

Comment: `which php` might  be better than `whereis php`. The latter gave me a huge paragraph, but the first gave me one simple path.

Comment: I have another cron job but is running a different PHP file (same directory of the leave_mail.php). That PHP file is not sending a request via CURL though. And there's no problem on that cron job. That's why I'm puzzled.

Comment: Can be that curl is in the disable_functions list in the php.ini.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions